# Excel: Using ISBLANK in conjunction with IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to develop a simple expiration date with conditional highlighting. I've set up the column I to an IF statement based on a logic test in column G, drawing value from Column A. Formula is currently:

```
=IF(G2="N", A2+7,A2+60)
```

Problem is, I'm making this for a complete excel newbie so I need it foolproof. I want column I to remain blank as long as either cells in the corresponding column A or G are blank (not relevant which, they'll both be filled together). I've tried a few nested and "AND" statements to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR` to test if either A2 *or* G2 is blank using the `ISBLANK` function:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(G2)),"",IF(G2="N",A2+7,A2+60))
```

If so, you can return `""` if either input is blank, and if both are populated then go ahead and use your original formula.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `COUNTA` function to determine how many cells are populated and only use the `IF` function if the result is 2, e.g.

`=IF(COUNTA(A2,G2)=2,IF(G2="N",A2+7,A2+60),"")`